# can I create an ArrayList of instances of a specific class?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to come over to java from C++ and am having some difficulties.  In C++ I could make a list of specific class instances (such as a list of an employee class, which would include name, bday etc..).  In java, however I am having a harder time figuring out the same function.  In C++ I would use pointers in such, in Java it appears that it is suggested to use an ArrayList.  However creating an array list and feeding it class instances works, but I cant access those class instances again.
I do not really have any code examples, because I am just looking to be pointed in the right direction at this time, and just try things out.  So any suggestions would be more then appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using generics:

```
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
employees.add(new Employee());
Employee employee = employees.get(0);
```

Take a look at the documentation of [`ArrayList<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and [`List<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html), which is the interface.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I have poured over the documentation several times, but I had never seen the .get().  But that was it, that was what I was missing thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have pointed out, generics provide the best solution.

However, you can also solve the problem the old-fashioned way with explicit typecasts; e.g.

```
List employees = new ArrayList();
employees.add(new Employee());
...
Employee employee = (Employee) employee.get(0);
```

This is the way you had to solve this problem in Java prior to Java 1.5.

---

By the way, the code generated by the Java compiler would include a typecast instruction *even if you used generics* ... as in Binyamin Sharet's version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an arraylist with templating as it would be called in c++ so it would look like

```
ArrayList<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
```

This way any object you access from the list is already automatically cast to MyObject which avoids the manual cast you would have to do in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generified list as follows:

```
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
employees.add(new Employee());
```

Generics is all about compile time type safety. Compiler won't let you add anything but instances of `Employee` in that list.

You can loop through the list as follows:

```
for(Employee employee : employees) {
    // use employee
}
```

But if you want to modify the list itself while iterating, then you have to use an `Iterator`.

```
Iterator<Employee> it = employees.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    Employee emp = it.next();
    //or it.remove(); to remove the element from the list
}
```

`List`s in Java maintain the order of the elements in which they were added to the list.

Answer (score 0):

BTW in java it is not mandatory to use ArrayList. If your size is known and you want bit of performance you can use java arrays.

Regarding pointers in C++, in java everything (except primitives like int, float etc.) is a reference which is analogous to pointers in C++.

Say i use array as an example:

Java:

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
Employee[] empArray = new Employee[10];
// This is similar to C++ STL
List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

// Array just points to the object as pointer in C++
empArray[0] = emp;

empList.add(emp);
```

C++:

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
Employee * empArray = new Employee[10];
list<Employee> L;
```

For more:

[Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)
[Java Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)
[To create an analogy b/w Java and C++](http://rokoder.com/techblog/java-to-c/)